# Is exam expired or not using laravel controller

Tags: laravel

I have two dates one is exam_start_date_time and exam_end_Date_time.When i click on "start Exam"it goes to laravel function and checks if current datetime is passed end datetime it need to show "exam expired" else it start the exam.

```
$t1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($questionData->exam_end_date_time);
$t2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($questionData->exam_start_date_time);
if (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->gte($t1)){
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Exam Expired !!');
}
```

but here i get exam expired even the exam enddatetime remains time to close .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$t1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($questionData->exam_end_date_time);
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

if($t1 < $now)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Exam Expired !!');
}
```

Comment: its not working, still time remains and shows exam is expired

Comment: show me your `$questionData->exam_end_date_time` value ? format ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this....

i think it will work for you

```
$endTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($questionData->exam_end_date_time);
    $startTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($questionData->exam_start_date_time);
         if (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->between($endTime,$startTime)){
               return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Exam Expired !!');
         }else{
            $left = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($endTime ,false);
            $left = Carbon::now()->diffInDays($endTime ,false);
            $left = Carbon::now()->diffInHours($endTime ,false);
            return redirect()->back()->with('info', $left.'Time Left !!');
         }
```

Comment: if exam is on 22/09/2020 and start time is 12.00 pm and end time is 1.00 pm. and current time is 12.42pm then exam have time. its not finished. then the exam is not expired

Comment: what do you want ? which variable are you using ? min,hours,days ?

Comment: min is using beacuse i have a timer here.

Comment: use `$left.' Minute Time Left !!'

Comment: check local time configuration

Comment: @SindhuDiya go config folder and set your time  'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka', or your country ... i think it will help you

Comment: if press start of exam  before actual startdate of exam ,how should i test that condition

Comment: it will be like this... `if(\Carbon\Carbon::now() < $startTime){}` ...

Comment: @SindhuDiya where are you ? are your problem did  not  solve yet ?